# Cisco 1841 "LICENSE-2-VLS_ERROR" and "ALIGN-3-SPURIOUS" errors

Tags: cisco

I've got a Cisco 1841 (revision 7.0) router. It shows me this message during the boot process:

```
*Jan 14 11:17:03.739: %LICENSE-2-VLS_ERROR: 'VLSaddLicenseStorage' failed with an error - rc = 143 - 'Error[143]: Failure in accessing the specified store.'
-Traceback= 6032B398z 62AA6704z 62AA67B0z 62AA6928z 6107423Cz 610744D8z 62A3E35Cz 62A3E340z
*Jan 14 11:17:03.743: license_register_license_storage failed with error = 24
```

And some time (approximately 5 minutes after boot process is completed) it shows this message:

```
Router#
*Jan 14 11:27:37.199: %ALIGN-3-SPURIOUS: Spurious memory access made at 0x603778ACz  reading 0x4
*Jan 14 11:27:37.199: %ALIGN-3-TRACE: -Traceback= 0x603778ACz 0x610A4E4Cz 0x610AB370z 0x610BA7CCz 0x62A3E35Cz 0x62A3E340z 0xFFFF7200z 0xFFFF7200z
Router#
Router#
```

As you see, I did a `write erase` to eliminate the influence of configuration, so the router is reset, and this messages still occur (1st during boot, 2nd some minutes after boot).

```
System image file is "flash:c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.151-4.M12a.bin"
```

Question is: how do I treat this error messages? What's going on? Is it critical?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a really late respons. But dug up an 1841 that had been lying dormant for some years. And came across this post by google.

I tried the latest 151-4.M12a.bin. Believe this release came as an extra due to an ntp vulnerability.

Not the same problem as you. Had a problem that it rebooted from time to time.
Tried to look at it, and found it to completely crash when i did an udp scan with nmap, from the inside to an ouside server.

Had to settle for c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.151-4.M10.bin, and looks fine thus far.

So, stay away from c1841-advipservicesk9-mz.151-4.M12a.bin

From your post, it looks like you have a memory problem. But often needed to format the flash with the current ios you intend to use.